# How to find gnome-terminal currently used profile with cmd line?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to be able to tell which profile is used by a given terminal emulator. Just the name would be enough.

It's trivial to find with GUI : just right click in the terminal window, and the profile in use will be indicated under "Profiles". You can also go Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Profile Name.

I would like to access that information with command line, but can't find how.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following script in https://github.com/helino/current-gnome-terminal-profile/blob/master/current-gnome-terminal-profile.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

FNAME="$HOME/.current_gnome_profile"
gnome-terminal --save-config=$FNAME
ENTRY=`grep ProfileID < $FNAME`
rm $FNAME
TERM_PROFILE=${ENTRY#*=}
echo -n "$TERM_PROFILE"
```

Comment: I'm afraid that script won't work on newer versions:
"Option "--save-config" is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal."

Comment: There is an open issue about that -> https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/7673#submitted-by-christian-persch-chpe

Comment: I found this:  https://superuser.com/questions/198046/access-the-name-of-the-gnome-terminal-profile-from-the-command-line